# What does "numeric" redirect mean in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I found command like this

```
(MYVAR=0 ./mybinary --my-arg myval) < ../input 5> ../output/5 1> ../output/1
```

What does `5>` and `1>` mean?

Answer (score 1):

These are references to previously opened file descriptor.

See [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082001/how-do-file-descriptors-work)